# Postgres: Is libxslt xslt 1.0 or 2.0?

Tags: postgresql, xslt-2.0

Considering postgres for a project involving some xslt 2.0 transforms.

Reading the docs at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xml2.html, and I can't find the answer.

I hope it's 2.0, but I suspect it is not.

**Jan 2015 Update**, [here](http://nbsoftsolutions.com/blog/xslt-2-0-processing-in-postgres) I learned:

- xml/xslt is slated for removal from Postgres :(
- the blog author suggests a method to put Saxon-HE into Postgres :)

(*I'm not affiliated with the linked blog*)

Comment: You can find answer using your package manager by inspecting postgresql dependencies.

Comment: Try to use a any XSLT 2.0 element and find out.

Comment: I don't have it installed at the moment. Wanted to know the answer before seeing if I want to do that. I guess I'll go to Bitnami and download the LAMP virtual machine and try that out first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libxslt implements XSLT 1.0. Here was its initial scope:

> Libxslt-0.1.0 is the first beta release, it should cover 
>   most features from the XSLT-1.0 spec but it's clearly not
>   complete yet. Check the FEATURES file to get a precise idea.

Here is it's current scope:

> Libxslt is the XSLT C library developed for the GNOME project. XSLT itself is a an XML language to define transformation for XML. Libxslt is based on libxml2 the XML C library developed for the GNOME project. It also implements most of the EXSLT set of processor-portable extensions functions and some of Saxon's evaluate and expressions extensions.

- [The XSLT C library for GNOME: libxslt](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/xslt.html)
- [libxslt module: Extra](http://xmlsoft.org/XSLT/html/libxslt-extra.html)
- [libxslt FEATURES](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/libxslt/libxslt-8.1/libxslt/FEATURES)
- [libxslt 0.1.0 beta release](http://xml.coverpages.org/libxslt-Ann.html)